# Plesk and MailScanner

Tags: mailscanner

Plesk has spam filtering features using SpamAssassin you can buy. But I was wondering, what if I just install [Mailscanner](http://www.mailscanner.info/)? I mean, MailScanner installs itself in the postfix/exim/qmail pipeline and just lets the MTA deliver it normally.

But because Plesk does it's own voodoo inside my Ubuntu install, I'm not sure if this would work. I mean, will it conflict with settings Plesk does to the mail system?

Comment: I learned that mailscanner doesn't even support qmail...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I don't think it is off topic. It's not about a service provider's panel, it's about installing a panel on my own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't install something like Mailscanner on a system that is management by an external tool like Plesk. Both Mailscanner and Plesk change a lot of things and expect certain conditions.

Mailscanner brings a lot of packages and is not that easy to set up, btw. You really have to know what you're doing. If you're using the Ubuntu package, it's a little bit after the current Mailscanner stable release - but if you install from source, you won't get that warm and comforting feeling of your Plesk setup (Install it on another machine and you'll know what I mean).

Maybe you're better of if you add some simple restrictions to your `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` line (main.cf of postfix, if you use it). See [the Spamhaus ZEN blocklist](http://www.spamhaus.org/zen/) and a [Greylisting server](http://postgrey.schweikert.ch/) - these can be added really fast without breaking anything and stop a huge amount of spam.

Comment: I already enabled Zen, but I don't really know how effective it is. The Plesk machine is question is not yet used for our customers (it will soon though). Greylisting is not an option; I don't want to include delays, which can be annoying for forum registration mails etc.

Comment: The delay for greylisting will just be for the first individual hit. It remembers the accepted to-from-combinations; and you can whitelist. To see how effective Zen is, do something like `grep NOQUEUE /var/log/mail| grep -i spamhaus| wc -l`